# java void functional programming, tight coupling and boilerplate

Tags: java, functional-programming, boilerplate, tightly-coupled-code

When target Objects `excelColumns`, `pdfColumns` partly share same Objects and some of them even conditionally, what is a good OOP pattern to void functional programming, tight coupling and boilerplate like in code below? Lets assume, that there will be a lot of shared columns and only few non shared and conditional ones.

```
    List<Column> excelColumns = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Column> pdfColumns = new ArrayList<>();

    //shared columns
    Column test = new Column("test", 121, 11);
    excelColumns.add(test);
    pdfColumns.add(test);

    //conditional columns
    if (condition) {
        excelColumns.add(new Column("test2", 12, 21));
    }

    //non shared columns
    pdfColumns.add(new Column("test3", 12, 41));

    //shared columns
    Column test4 = new Column("test4", 12, 331);
    excelColumns.add(test4);
    pdfColumns.add(test4);
    Column test5 = new Column("test5", 72, 11);
    excelColumns.add(test5);
    pdfColumns.add(test5);
    Column test6 = new Column("test6", 82, 121);
    excelColumns.add(test6);
    pdfColumns.add(test6);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your appetite for complexity, you can do the following:

1. Try to group related columns instances into objects like `HeaderColumns`, `BodyColumns`, etc.
2. Implement the visitor pattern as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Here is a possible implementation of the pattern following the suggestions above:

```java
public class Main {

    interface Visitor {
        void visit(ReportHeader header);

        void visit(ReportBody body);
    }

    interface Visitable {
        void accept(Visitor visitor);
    }

    static class ReportHeader implements Visitable {

        private final List<String> columns = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> extras = new ArrayList<>();

        @Override
        public void accept(Visitor visitor) { visitor.visit(this); }

        public List<String> getColumns() { return columns; }

        public List<String> getExtras() { return extras; }
    }

    static class ReportBody implements Visitable {

        private final List<String> columns = new ArrayList<>();

        @Override
        public void accept(Visitor visitor) { visitor.visit(this); }

        public List<String> getColumns() { return columns; }
    }

    static class ExcelReportVisitor implements Visitor {

        private final List<String> columns = new ArrayList<>();

        @Override
        public void visit(ReportHeader header) {
            columns.addAll(header.getColumns());
            columns.addAll(header.getExtras());
        }

        @Override
        public void visit(ReportBody body) { columns.addAll(body.getColumns()); }
    }

    static class PdfReportVisitor implements Visitor {

        private final List<String> columns = new ArrayList<>();

        @Override
        public void visit(ReportHeader header) {
            columns.addAll(header.getColumns());
            // no extras for PDF
        }

        @Override
        public void visit(ReportBody body) { columns.addAll(body.getColumns()); }
    }
}
```

You could use it as follows:

```java
public static void main(String args[]) {
    ReportHeader header = new ReportHeader();
    ReportBody body = new ReportBody();

    List<Visitor> visitors = Arrays.asList(new PdfReportVisitor(), new ExcelReportVisitor());
    visitors.forEach(each -> {
        each.visit(header);
        each.visit(body);
    });

    // do something with the visitors like `visitor.exportReport()`
}
```

Advantages of this approach:

1. Every time you have to add a new report section to `Visitor`, it will generate a compile error in all visitor implementations. That avoids typical programming mistakes where people forget to add branches to `if` or `switch` statements.
2. The conditional logic on how to build the report is placed in the actual implementation of the report. No need for conditional anymore.

Disadvantages of this approach:

1. For sure the complexity given the additional abstractions you will be required to create.
2. Sometimes it might not make sense or possible to encapsulate/group your `Column` instances into semantically cohesive objects. For example, you might end with weirdness in `ReportHeader` like this:

```java
static class ReportHeader implements Visitable {

    private final List<String> columns = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> extras = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> dataThatIsOnlyUsedByExcelReport = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void accept(Visitor visitor) { visitor.visit(this); }

    public List<String> getColumns() { return columns; }

    public List<String> getExtras() { return extras; }

    public List<String> getDataThatIsOnlyUsedByExcelReport() { return dataThatIsOnlyUsedByExcelReport; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addAll(...)` method instead `add(...)` for the last shared columns section to add them all for every collection. If you goal is to maintain a conditional order of inserting next columns, there is no point to obfuscate it, because here it is clearly presented.

Comment: thanks @marcin.programuje, but how to void tight coupling between `excelColumns` and  `pdfColumns`, lets say I want to have implementations in different classes?

Comment: Then you can use the Strategy pattern. Assuming you want to have ```excelColumns``` collection building process separated from ```pdfColumns``` collection building process you can made a class ```ExcelColumnsBuildingStrategy``` ```PdfColumnsBuildingStrategy```. Both class will implement same interface ```ColumnsBuildingStrategy```. More info here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/strategy_pattern.htm